# Element of, subset of and empty sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to make sense of these. To me a is false because the set isn't empty. Is that correct?

b is true because the empty set is an element of that set.

c is false because the set the empty set isn't an element, it is a subset or proper subset.

d is true because the set the empty set is a member of that set.

e the set the empty set is false because it is not a proper subset I think

f false for the same reason

g false for the same

> a) ∅ ∈ {∅}
>
> b) ∅ ∈ {∅, {∅}}
>
> c) {∅} ∈ {∅}
>
> d) {∅} ∈ {{∅}}
>
> e) {∅} ⊂ {∅, {∅}}
>
> f ) {{∅}} ⊂ {∅, {∅}}
>
> g) {{∅}} ⊂ {{∅}, {∅}}

I know not all these are correct, why is my logic wrong?

Comment: No, (a) is true: no matter what $a$ is, $a\in\{a\}$, because by definition $\{a\}$ is the set whose only element is $a$.

Comment: e) is also true, since $A\subset B$ means that every element of $A$ is also an element of $B$.

Comment: (f) is true: the only element of $\{\{\varnothing\}\}$ is $\{\varnothing\}$, which is also an element of the righthand side. Whether (g) is true or false depends on whether you’re using $\subset$ to mean *subset* or *proper subset*; in the former case it’s true, and in the latter it’s false, since the righthand side is equal to the lefthand side.

Comment: I don't even know how to **parse** "the set the empty set is false". What do you mean by "the set the empty set"? And how can a "set" be true or false?

Comment: @bof  {∅}  that is the set the empty set, like {1} is the set containing 1, or {{1}} is the set the set containing 1. Anyways I meant to say the statement is false.

Comment: I knew what you meant by it, but *the set the empty set* just isn’t English; what you’re trying to say, I think, is that $\{\varnothing\}$ is the set whose only member is the empty set. Similarly, $\{\{1\}\}$ is the set whose only member is the set whose only member is $1$.

Comment: I would say that it *is* English, but it doesn't mean what the OP intends. To me it seems analogous to "the band the Beatles". Rather clumsy English, certainly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't argue too much, do it mechanically instead. If you wipe out the enclosing $\{$ and $\}$ you will see a list of the elements of the set, e.g., if $A=\{a,b,\{a\}\}$ then after removing the braces, this
$$a,b,\{a\}$$
is the list of elements of $A$, so
$$a\in A,\quad b\in A\quad \{a\}\in A.$$

You'll get any subset of $A$ by first removing the braces to get the element-list, then choose some elements and put braces around your chosen elements, for example
$$\{a,b\}\subset A,\quad \{a,\{a\}\}\subset A,\quad \{\{a\}\}\subset A.$$ So only (c) is wrong.  For example, (f) is true: get the element list of $M=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$ by removing braces:
$$\emptyset, \{\emptyset\},$$
chose the element $\emptyset$, (thus $\emptyset\in M$), put braces around your chosen element to get $\{\emptyset\}$, to yield a subset of $M$, that is $\{\emptyset\}\subset M$.

Comment: There is not an iota mention of the phrase 'proper-subset' in your answer.

Comment: Not only c, g is wrong too. A set can't be proper set of itself.