# Question about a subset

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Why is this thing true
 $$\{\{\varnothing\}\}\subset\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$$

I'm trying to underestand, but I need an explanation.

Comment: Do you have a definition of what it means to be a subset? What are the elements of $\{\{\varnothing\}\}$? What are the elements of $\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$?

Comment: 1) {ø}, 2) ø,{ø}

Comment: This http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527819/element-of-subset-of-and-empty-sets/528184#528184 will help.

Answer (score 10):

Referring to the **definition of the inclusion**: *a set $A$ is included in another set $B$ if and only if all elements of set $A$ belongs to set $B$.*

Just apply it to $$A=\{\{\varnothing\}\}, \ B=\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}.$$ What are the elements of $A=\{\{\varnothing\}\}$? There is only one which is $\{\varnothing\}$. Is $\{\varnothing\}$ an element of $B$? The answer is yes.

**Conclusion: $$A \subset B.$$**

Answer (score 4):

Let $A$ be a set; then $\{ \{ A \} \} \subset \{ A, \{ A \} \}$, for $\{ A \}$ belongs to the latter class. If you understand this,  take $A := \varnothing$ and your problem is solved.

Comment: So {{ø}}c{ø,{ø}} is true?

Comment: Yes; by definition it is; nothing mysterious here.

Answer (score 3):

If $x \in \{\{\varnothing\}\}$ then $x = \{\varnothing\}$

Since $ x \in \{\varnothing,x\}$ then $ x \in \{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$

Hence $x \in \{\{\varnothing\}\}$ implies $x \in \{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$

So $\{\{\varnothing\}\}\subseteq\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$

Answer (score 2):

{{$\varnothing$}} is a set that has one element in it.  Its element is {$\varnothing$}; a set that contains only the empty set as a member.

{$\varnothing$, {$\varnothing$}} is a set with two elements in it.  The first element is the empty set.  The second element is the same element above:  The set {$\varnothing$}; the set that contains only the empty set as a member.

Both sets contain the element {$\varnothing$}

Every element in the first set (it has only one) is also a member of the second set (it has two).  So the first set is a subset of the second.

Comment: I did underestand thanks so much you two ^^