# which of the following are true for the follwing sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let Let A={∅,{∅,{∅}}} B=∅,C={∅},D={∅,{∅}} Which of the following are true,

a). $C\subseteq A\;\;b) \;C\epsilon A\;\; c)\; B\epsilon A\; d)\; B\subseteq A\;e)\;B\epsilon C\;f)\;C=B\;g)\;C\subseteq D\;h)\;C\epsilon D\;i)\;D\subseteq A $

My attempt :a is wright and b is wright confusing about c

Comment: b) $C$ is the set containing the empty set, does $A$ also have a set containing the empty set only?

Comment: sorry i am not understand @ bubububu

Comment: if u know right answet can u expalin me

Comment: $C\in A$ means that $C$ is an element of $A$, but as you see, there is no such element (a set containing the empty set only)

Comment: You should spend some time on learning how to write math symbols. This site uses
[MathJax formatting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Comment: [Latex Math symbols](http://web.ift.uib.no/Teori/KURS/WRK/TeX/symALL.html)

Comment: @JKnecht..sorry i am new i learn ,,thanks

Comment: No problem, it was just an advice because you are new

Comment: if any one knows this answer can u hele me

Comment: These are all sets.  The elements of the sets are other sets.  B is the empty set and has no elements.  C is a set that contains element-- that element is C. So f is false.  C and B are different sets.  e is true because B, the empty set, is an element of C, the set that contains the empty set.  D is a set with two elements.  These elements are the empty set, and the set containing the empty set.  g is true because every element of C is an element of D.  h is true because C itself is an element D.

Comment: Nearly a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527819/element-of-subset-of-and-empty-sets/528184#528184

Answer (score 1):

This question is about 
whats the difference between being 
an element of a set and being a subset of a set

Consider

$A=\{a,b,c,\{a,b\},\{b,c,d\}\}$

$a$ is an element of the set $A$.

The set $\{a,b\}$ is an element of the set $A$.

The set $\{b,c,d\}$ is an element of the set $A$

The set $\{b,c\}$ is a subset of $A$.

The set $\{a\}$ is a subset of $A$.

$\subseteq$ means subset of

$\in$ means an element of