# Is $\{a, b\}$ a subset of $\big\{\{a, b\}\big\}\;?$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I read a lot of questions like that here, but it takes me more confused.

In many books appear examples like:
$\textbf{A} = \{a, b, c\}$, so:
$\{a\}\subset\textbf{A}$ ,
$\{b, c\}\subset\textbf{A}$ etc.

But here I read things like: 
If $\;\textbf{B}=\big\{a,b,\{c, d\}\big\}$, so $\textbf{B}$ has $3$ members:
$a\in\textbf{B}$ ,
$b\in\textbf{B}$ ,
$\{c, d\}\in\textbf{B}$ , *but* : 
$c\not\in\textbf{B}$ and $d\not\in\textbf{B}$.

It made me more confused because: 
If there is $x\in\textbf{P}$ and $\textbf{P}\subset\textbf{Q}$, so $x\in\textbf{Q}$. 
E.g.: $1\in\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z\subset\mathbb R$, so $1\in\mathbb R$.

In this case: 
$\{c, d\}\subset\textbf{B}$ ? 
$\big\{\{c, d\}\big\}\subset\textbf{B}$ ? 
$\{c\}\subset\textbf{B}$ ? 
$\big\{\{c\}\big\}\subset\textbf{B}$ ?

Comment: "Subset of" means that every element of the "left" set is also an element of the "right" set: $A \subseteq B$.

Comment: In order: no, yes, no, no.

Comment: No, see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527819/element-of-subset-of-and-empty-sets/528184#528184

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Element of, subset of and empty sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527819/element-of-subset-of-and-empty-sets)

Comment: If $c=a$ then also $c\in B$...

Comment: Every level of curls in the definition of a set plays its role.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I really appreciate and liked your answer, but when I start to correlate those conclusions with definitions and axioms of set theory, it goes crazy. Even when I do Venn diagrams. That’s why I wrote the example of the set of Integers and Reals.

Answer (score 4):

The Definition:

> $A \subset B \hspace{10pt}$  iff $\hspace{10pt} \forall x \hspace{3pt}\big(\hspace{2pt}x \in A \implies x \in B \hspace{2pt}\big)$

That is,
$A\subset B\hspace{5pt}$  iff $\;$ every element of $A$ is also an element of $B$.

Let's take example in the title: $A = \{a, b\}, B = \big\{\{a, b\}\big\}$

$A$ has two elements: $a$ and $b$. 
$B$ has only one element:  the set $\{a, b\}$

Is $a $ in $B$? No, it is not! $B$ has only one element that is the set $\{a, b\}$ which is not the element $a$. 
Hence, it is clear that an element of $A$ is not an element of $B$. 
Thus $A$ is not a subset of $B$.

Comment: So **A** being an element of **B** and **A** being a set, doesn't implies **A** being a subset **B**, right?

Comment: @GDX, Yes by definition of subset.